# VBA to send Word Mail Merge

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

When attempting to run this code I get an object required error. I am not sure how to resolve this.

I am trying to run vba from excel to run mail merge in word.

```
Sub MailMerge()
    Set wordapp = CreateObject("word.Application")
    wordapp.documents.Open "C:\Users\me\Desktop\hello.docx", ReadOnly:=True
    wordapp.Visible = True


            With ActiveDocument.MailMerge
        .Destination = wdSendToEmail
        .SuppressBlankLines = True
        With .DataSource
            .FirstRecord = wdDefaultFirstRecord
            .LastRecord = wdDefaultLastRecord
        End With
        .Execute Pause:=False
    End With


End Sub
```

Comment: since you are referring to word vba object model inside of Excel instance, you will need to refactor your code. Using early binding can help tremendously with this; otherwise, you will have to find the enumeration values for things `wdDefaultFirstRecord` and such, and refrain from using `ActiveDocument`. Excel does not now what those things since it's not in its object model.

Comment: When asking a question about an error please always provide the *line of code* that triggers the error.

Answer (score 1):

Since this is running in Excel VBA the code needs to specifically reference what belongs to Word. That means that this line:

```
With ActiveDocument.MailMerge
```

Needs to be

```
With wordApp.ActiveDocument.MailMerge
```

Since Excel knows nothing about `ActiveDocument`. Even better, however, would be to assign an object to the Document when it's opened, rather than rely on `ActiveDocument`:

```
Dim wordDoc as Object
Set wordDoc = wordapp.documents.Open("C:\Users\me\Desktop\hello.docx", ReadOnly:=True)
With wordDoc.MailMerge
```

Once you have that working, you'll get additional error messages for all the enumeration values starting with `wd`. These, too, belong to Word VBA. Since you're using `Object` instead of `Word.Application` for `wordapp` the code *cannot* use the `wd` enumerations - VBA can't look them up. Using `Word.Application` would mean needing to set a Reference to the Word object model in Tools/References. This can make it difficult if the macro needs to be used by other people with a different (older) version of Office, which is why many code samples for running Word from Excel use `Object`.

If you want to use `Object` then you need to replace all the `wd` enumeration values with their numerical equivalent. `wdSendToEmail` for example has the value 2, so

```
.Destination = 2
```

I leave it to you to look up the other values, which is simple enough. Open Word's VBA editor, press F2 to open the object browser, then search each `wd` value. The numeric equivalent will be at the very bottom of the window when you click on a value.

[image]